# Trying to display list of members

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, database

For some reason I'm trying to display all of the members from the database in a list in order to access each of their profiles when I click on them, but I'm only getting the link of the last person in the database, any help?

```
include_once "../../mysql_server/connect_to_mysql.php";

//This code is used to display friends in the box of friends
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers");
$numberofRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$memberDisplayList = 'There are ' . $numberofRows .' members<br /><br />';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $id = $row['id']; 
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"];

    ///////  Mechanism to Display Pic. See if they have uploaded a pic or not 
    $check_pic = "../../members/$id/image01.jpg";
    $default_pic = "../../members/0/image01.jpg";
    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
        $user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic?$cacheBuster\" width=\"80px\" />"; 
    } else {
        $user_pic = "<img src=\"$default_pic\" width=\"80px\" />"; 
    }

    $memberDisplayList = '<a href="http://www.pathtosite.com/friends_page.php?id='. $id .'">' . $firstname .' '. $lastname .'</a><br />';   
}
// ------- END WHILE LOOP FOR GETTING THE MEMBER DATA ---------
```

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of

```
$memberDisplayList = '<a href= (...etc)
```

you meant to type

```
$memberDisplayList .= '<a href= (...etc)
```

which would append the new links to your string.

Also you don't seem to be echoing your `$user_pic` and `$memberDisplayList` strings anywhere.

Comment: YESSS thank you, and I echo the code below but it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Its because your overwriting the variables on each iteration, you need to hold the data within an array then do another foreach loop where ever you output:

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ///////  Mechanism to Display Pic. See if they have uploaded a pic or not  //////////////////////////
    $check_pic = "../../members/{$row['id']}/image01.jpg";
    $default_pic = "../../members/0/image01.jpg";
    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
        $user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic?$cacheBuster\" width=\"80px\" />";
    } else {
        $user_pic = "<img src=\"$default_pic\" width=\"80px\" />";
    }

    $user[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],
                    'firstname'=>$row["firstname"],
                    'lasname'=>$row["lastname"],
                    'user_pic'=>$user_pic,
                    'display_list'=>'<a href="http://www.pathtosite.com/friends_page.php?id='. $row['id'].'">' . $row["firstname"] .' '. $row["lastname"] .'</a><br />');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you actually constructing the HTML?  You're setting a bunch of variables in the code you presented, and that looks okay for what it is.  So it's probably in the presentation logic.  If that's in the loop, you're in good shape.  But if it's outside of the loop, then I can't imagine where you'd ever display anything  but the last row.